# For any three relations prove the $ (T \circ S) \circ R = T \circ (S \circ R) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

> Prove: For any three relations $R \subset W \times X$, $S \subset X \times Y$, and $T \subset Y \times Z$, $(T \circ S) \circ R = T \circ (S \circ R)$.

[(image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGw2h.png)

**Attempted Proof:** suppose  $ (a,b)  \in T \circ (S \circ R)$ then $ \exists  (a,x) \in T \wedge (x,b) \in (S \circ R)  $.

Since $ (x,b) \in (S \circ R) \exists  (x,y) \in S \wedge (y,b) \in R $ and since $ (a,x) \in T \wedge (x,y) \in S \implies (a,y) \in (T \circ S)$ and $(y,b) \in R$

$\therefore  (a,b) \in (T \circ S) \circ R = T \circ (S \circ R) $

Is this correct?

Comment: Please do not use images to convey information that is not otherwise present in the body of your post. [See here for an explanation of why this is bad practice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742)

Comment: You say $(a,b) \in (T \circ S) \circ R = T \circ (S \circ R)$ but that's not what you  have proved. You have proved that if $(a,b) \in T \circ (S \circ R)$ then $(a,b)\in (T \circ S) \circ R$. So you have so far only proved $T \circ (S \circ R)\subseteq (T \circ S) \circ R$. You need to do the reverse inclusion.